# jQuery date format returning wrong time

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime-format

I've got an input date as the following:

> Thu May 17 2012 18:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

However, with the following :

```
var dateString = 'hu May 17 2012 18:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)';

document.write($.format.date(dateString, "ddd MMMM dd, HH:mm"));
```

The resulting output is 1 hour faster than I'd expect:

> Thursday May 17, 18:00

Seems to be ignoring the GMT+0100 (BST) part...
Is there anyway to get it to display as 17:00?

Comment: It's not faster, it's just not showing the time zone. Where does this string come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to convert the timezone explicitly. You can create a separate function for it.

Please check this link :

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329